# Hibernate version tag issue

Tags: java, hibernate

Hi I am working in Hibernate. I have come across a issue with version tag.

This is the version tag I am using:

```
<version name="version" type="java.lang.Integer" column="Version" access="property"  unsaved value="null" />
```

Below is the Id tag I am using

```
<id name="Id" type="java.lang.Long" >  
    <column name="ID" precision="22" scale="0" />  
    <generator class="sequence">  
        <param name="sequence">id_seq</param>
    </generator>
</id>
```

Since this table is used in many projects, so the version column they are inserting as null.

But in my application since I am using version tag , its excepting not null value and if null, it treats as insert and calls sequence generator and increments the Id, which creates me lot of problem.

How to overcome this issue ? Is possible to avoid calling seq generator and save version column to 1 if null?

Answer (score 1):

Simply define a DEFAULT value of 1 for that column in the database.

Comment: But some other application is explicitly inserting "NULL" to this column. So that column is getting saved as NULL inspite of having default value as 0

Comment: @Senthilnathan: find that other application and fix it. If you can't find it, change the column definition to NOT NULL and see who comes running.